# How do I use FirebaseUI with multiple datasources for a tableview?

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, uitableview, firebaseui

The documentation is sparse on FirebaseUI. How do I use different data sources for a tableview using FirebseUI?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a tableview that uses a single datasource, you can use the `FUIFirestoreTableViewDataSource` or `FirebaseTableViewDataSource`. You can bind either of them to a tableview using a query (such as an `FIRQuery`) thus:

```
let query: Query = self.db.collection("users").whereField("name", isEqualTo: "Taiwo")

self.dataSource = self.tableView.bind(toFirestoreQuery: query) { tableView, indexPath, snapshot in
   // get your data type out of the snapshot, create and return your cell.
}
```

This works very well for a tableview with a 'single source of truth' and makes your tableview react to changes etc in the database without much work from you.

However, in a case where you need to change the data on the fly (such as where you need to display different data based on user selection), using a datasource won't work. In this case, you need to use a backing collection from Firebase such as a `FUIBatchedArray` or `FUIArray`.

This isn't much different from using a Swift array alongside your tableview's datasource. The only significant difference is that you need to initialize the array using typically your viewcontroller as its delegate:

```
var datasourceArray = FUIBatchedArray(query: query, delegate: self)
```

Then

```
extension MyViewController: FUIBatchedArrayDelegate {
   func batchedArray(_ array: FUIBatchedArray, didUpdateWith diff: FUISnapshotArrayDiff<DocumentSnapshot>) {
        // you'll receive changes to your array in `diff` and `array` is a whole array with 
        // all new changes together with old data
        datasourceArray = array
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.tableView.reloadData()
        }
    }

    func batchedArray(_ array: FUIBatchedArray, willUpdateWith diff: FUISnapshotArrayDiff<DocumentSnapshot>) {

    }

    func batchedArray(_ array: FUIBatchedArray, queryDidFailWithError error: Error) {

    }
}
```

Then you can use `datasourceArray` as you would a Swift array in your UITableViewDataSource methods:

```
extension MyViewController: UITableViewDataSource {
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return datasourceArray.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let snapshot = datasourceArray.object(at: indexPath.row)

        do {
            let task = try snapshot.data(as: Task.self)
            // create, customise and return your cell
            }
        }
        catch {
            print("coudln't get data out of snapshot", error.localizedDescription)
        }

        return UITableViewCell()
    }
}
```